# AG-Grid Infinite Row Model - Increase the scroll buffer or load the records even earlier (Pre-fetch Cache Blocks)

Tags: angular, ag-grid, infinite-scroll, ag-grid-angular

Have implemented AG Grid Infinite Row Model in Angular with Datasource and the grid automatically loads new records when scrolled to the bottom of the grid. But I want to load the next set of records much earlier and don't want to wait until the user scrolls to the end of the grid.

Eg: When the user scrolls to the last ten records, I want to load the next set of records.

How to achieve this and increase the scroll buffer? How to prefetch the next block of data without the user knowing?

I don't see an option to update the scroll buffer or manually call the getRows function